Connect to jupyter notebook in Azure
I'm trying to set up a connection between a jupyter notebook running in a virtual machine on Azure from my local machine. My objective is to have a notebook running in that virtual machine as a server, so other teams can use it to read and/or create another notebooks there.
How can I do that? First of all, I'm having problems connecting to the virtual machine from my local.
I've downloaded the ssh key and I'm running ssh -i <mykey> azureuser@ip as indicated in the Azure app, but the command hangs and eventually timeouts
After fixing that problem I would need to have a solution to access the notebook. I assume that accessing the port where the jupyter kernel is running should be enough, but wanted to be sure.
Could you give me some details about this process?

This is missing some details to give a meaningful answer. How much access to the Azure portal do you have? And maybe even more importantly, why are you trying to do this? At least to me, from a generic IT perspective, this reads very much like an XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

I've edited the question @KonTheCat . As a summary, I want to have that notebook running as a server so other teams can use it

Make sure to check if the Jupyter server is running on the VM and also verify that the port of the Jupyter server is allowed in the NSG rule.
I have configured jupyter on Azure VM by following steps.
I installed required modules using below cmdlets.
    sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
    pip3 install jupyter
    pip install notebook
    jupyter-notebook --version
    export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PA
    jupyter notebook password  
    nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py 

Here is the jupyter configuration.
    c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'  
    c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'  
    c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
    c.NotebookApp.port = 8888 # Or any other desired port 

Start the Jupyter server by running the below command:
  jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888

Output:

NSG Rule configuration:

After running the above commands, I'm able to log in to the Jupyter server using the VM's public IP address

